# How to use Gnome in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: gnome-classic

How do I use Gnome in Ubuntu 13.04? I tried the following from this [site](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-classic-gnome-desktop-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail.html):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

But it seems to be buggy, `alt+tab` doesn't even work and when I'm grabbing a particular window it grabs the one behind it instead. The gnome desktop feels faster on my machine and I find it easier to navigate with it, is there another way of using gnome in Ubuntu 13.04 aside from the method above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the GNOME3 desktop environment, install gnome-shell:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

For the old GNOME2 desktop, install gnome-panel:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`

You can install both of them if you like, and choose at the logon screen.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, install Compiz configuration settings manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

then run `ccsm` and enabled the **Aplication Switcher** plugin:

[image]

About the grabbing window issue, I've never saw that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should first install gnome to your computer.
To install;
open terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool
```

and if you want completely install gnome, also use this command

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

There is also a nice guide on this [side](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/05/gnome-shell-38-and-extensions-for.html).

After installation completed, restart computer and select gnome mode at the login screen (by clicking the icon next to the username on login screen)

Comment: have you tried this one? is it bug free?